# Try catch whole block in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I know how to make a try-catch from a single function. But the problem is I want to try-catch whole block of code - simple if something goes wrong ignore whole block.

Let me show you simple example. This is a simple parser from Facebook graph api for /me/taggable_friends:

```
let params:[NSObject : AnyObject] = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, id, picture"]
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/taggable_friends", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "GET") 
request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            else{

                let resultDictionary:NSDictionary! = result as! [String: AnyObject]
                let array = resultDictionary["data"] as! NSArray
                for object in array {
                    let firstName = object["first_name"] as! String
                    let lastName = object["last_name"] as! String
                    let tagId = object["id"] as! String
                    let picture = object["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                    let pictureData = picture["data"] as! NSDictionary
                    let pictureUrl = pictureData["url"] as! String

                    let friend = FacebookFriend(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, tagId: tagId, picture: pictureUrl)

                    print(pictureUrl)

                    self.friends.append(friend)
                }


            }
        }
```

That code is working and will quietly fail is error is not nil. But let's say facebook has changed something or somehow some values in json aren't available. App will crash. So I have to make if-let statements for almost every line of this code. Soon it'll make it long and hard to read. In java I'd just make a try-catch for a whole block. But in swift I don't know how do that. What's more compiler is saying that "as!" (so unwrapping optional value) can't raise an exception which is false :)

Answer (score 2):

This is where the `guard` statement comes in handy, the basic syntax is:

```
guard let foo = expression else {
    handle the error, and return (or throw)
}
```

In this case, you're wanting to protect a bunch of optional parsing from the vagaries of Facebook changing their API at some point in the future.  Using guard and continue in this case allows you to safely skip the rest of the block:

```
    for object in array {
        guard
            let firstName = object["first_name"] as? String,
            let lastName = object["last_name"] as? String,
            let tagId = object["id"] as? String,
            let picture = object["picture"] as? NSDictionary,
            let pictureData = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary,
            let pictureUrl = pictureData["url"] as? String else {
                print("JSON format has changed")
                continue
        }

        let friend = FacebookFriend(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, tagId: tagId, picture: pictureUrl)

        print(pictureUrl)

        self.friends.append(friend)
    }
```

Generally speaking, Swift try/catch blocks aren't really analogous to try/catch in other languages, particularly so for Java.  In Java all exceptions are (to some extent) handleable, even those such as null references, array bounds issues, etc.  In Swift, try/catch errors are definitively not meant to handle exceptions, but only meant to handle errors.  So there's no way to use try/catch to protect yourself from `as! String` failing.  You have to specifically expect and protect against the possibility, which is precisely where guard comes into play, potentially in combination with throw.

Comment: So basically guard will prevent my app from crashing if some keys (like first_name) won't be present in json, but still I'd have to add if-let for each of them? But if I'd just add if-lets won't it work the same?

Comment: `guard let` is a replacement (of sorts) for `if let`.  It is very similar except that with `if let foo = bar`, `foo` is only accessible in the success portion of the `if` statement.  With `guard let foo`, foo is accessible in the rest of the block containing the `guard let` so, as you see in the block above, you don't wind up with a bunch of nested `if let` blocks.  It also has a much more natural flow, since the exceptional case is handled immediately, and the major flow of the routine continues unabated.

Comment: Btw, `guard` can be used with any conditional, not just with `guard let`  What guard is doing is establishing preconditions for a block of code that must exist for the rest of the block to execute.  So you can also use something like `guard index < array.count else { throw index out of bounds }`

Answer (score 0):

To get values from json easier, you can use [SwiftyJSON framework](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). In situations like described in your question, you can get value that you need and wrap it in `if let` condition. For example (from SwiftyJSON Readme):

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[999999]["wrong_key"]["wrong_name"].string {
    //Calm down, take it easy, the ".string" property still produces the correct Optional String type with safety
} else {
    //Print the error
    print(json[999999]["wrong_key"]["wrong_name"])
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'd check it out.